# AJAX code not able to call a .php file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am not able to call a file: "fillDropDown.php".

```
function MakeRequest()
{
  var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
  try 
  {
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) 
        {
            HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "filldropdown.php", true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
  }
  catch(err)
  {
    alert(err);
  }
}
```

**Edited:
=======**

I am using AJAX code as suggested in this link:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/simple-ajax-php-and-javascript

Comment: what's the error you're getting? Are you sure the path is correct (it must be relative to the html page calling the javascript)?

Comment: Does `getXMLHttp()` return the correct XHR object depending on the browser?

Comment: ..and/or pop open the javascript console of your browser and tell us if there's an error message there.

Comment: It is not displaying any error nor passing control to that file.

Comment: please post a link where we can see the whole html+javascript code in action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that filldropdown.php script had errors. I fixed it and it is now running.

Answer (score 1):

Is `fillDropDown.php` the correct filename?

I just ask because you're calling `filldropdown.php`... Depending on your webserver and/or your operating system, file paths are case-sensitive!

Comment: Lol, just asked that exact same question :P

Comment: so the file name in the filesystem is exactly (case-sensitive): 'filldropdown.php' and not 'fillDropDown.php'?

Comment: What happens if you call `filldropdown.php` directly from your browser?

Comment: lol... you have fallen for one of the classic blunders, the most well known being "never start a land war in asia". Case sensitivity of file names is important in unix land!

this code will work on a windows server, but not a unix one..

you have to pay close attention to the case that you use. not all file systems are case insensitive.

Comment: easy enough to tes as well..
 try typing the file name into the webbrowser that you are using... If you get a file not found error with filldropdown.php but get success with fillDropDown.php, you will have located your error.

Answer (score 0):

How about with this?

```
function MakeRequest() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
          alert("Cool. It's work. :)");
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "filldropdown.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

Make sure, "filldropdown.php" should be in **same root** with the document which contain above script.

Comment: Didn't get any response? Didn't pop up an alert? Then, the problem might be in your "filldropdown.php". Did you echo something in your "filldropdown.php"?

Comment: Yes, I have added echo on the very top of the .php file.

Answer (score 0):

Without more code there is little we can do, doesn't look too bad but something I just want to clarify is that you are calling the file filldropdown.php but in your description you call it fillDropDown.php... case is important.